# How to initializeParse in expo router v2 project(using back4app parse server)?

Tags: react-native, parse-platform, back4app, expo-router

I am getting error when I pass `initializeParse()` command.

> [error: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined value to object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ykkjt.png)

> [when i press minimize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JB6aV.png)

> [onpressing sitemap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckzEm.png)

I have installed `npm install parse @parse/react-native --save` and `npm install @types/parse --save-dev`

**package.json**

```json
  "@parse/react-native": "^0.0.1-alpha.18",
  "parse": "^4.3.1",
  "@types/parse": "^3.0.9"
```

**code**

```js
import { initializeParse } from "@parse/react-native";

export default function HomeScreen() {
  
 initializeParse(
  'SERVER_URL',
  'APPLICATION_ID',
  'JAVASCRIPT_KEY'
);
  return ()
```

and my file layout is :

- _layout
- (tabs)

  - _layout
  - index -->Home Screen
  - location
  - profile
- (sections)

  - layout
  - about